# regex, find specific line, find specific word from this line

Tags: python, regex

I need explanation, how to write regex which will find:
 line contains `ABC -` and from this line word with 3 upper letters. Output should be full match, not in group
input

```
hello my ABC - is DAT
hello yours nns DAY
```

output full match should be: `DAT`

now i have only :
r''`ABC - .*[A-Z]{3}`'
I am using `df.column.str.extract( )`in my code

Comment: Group that pattern with `(...)` and access using `match.group(1)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew i dont know why but i cannot use match, thatys why i was looking for fullmatch regex to use extract. when i am using `match` even with lambda function i am receiving errors: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'match'` , or without lambda `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'match'`

Comment: I suspect `ABC - .*([A-Z]{3})` will do. And `df['column'].str.extract(r'ABC - .*?\b([A-Z]{3})\b')`, too.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew one more question, when i want to change this regex to take same words but only at the end of each line? i know i should add `$` but i dont know where, can you help?

Comment: If you want to get them at the end, put `$` at the end.

Comment: `ABC - .*?\b([A-Z]{3})\b$` should works? in generator doesn't `

Comment: If you do not know how to use regex testers you need to learn that first. My advice: test my suggestions in the target environment, I do not focus on online testers and how they work, they confuse a lot of people. Use `r'ABC - .*?\b([A-Z]{3})$'`. When testing online against *single multiline* inputs always enable `m`, `MULTILINE` mode

Comment: its seems to be working on regex tester but not on my enviroment, when i am adding `$` i am receiving blank cells. i have tried to use lambda function , but i am receiving error: ` AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'extract'`, i will try to connect str.extract with re.MULTILINE

Comment: Add full code to repro the issue to the question.

Comment: Really, doesn't `df['column'].str.extract(r'ABC - .*?\b([A-Z]{3})$')` work?

Comment: its working on test data, i dont knmow why doesn't on my enviroment. when i am adding `$` i am receiving nans, (mindblow) thanks for help i will try to find out why in my code

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew i have found interesting thing that you may be interested in. 
my input is same as in my question as dataframe, when i do: `a=df['column'].str.extract(r'ABC - .*?\b([A-Z]{3})$')` `print(a) is name object 'a'` in my envitoment when i print(a) i am receiving `name object df['column']` hmm any ideas?

Comment: No, please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: thanks for your time, the reason was additional character that i missed in my big dataset -.-'